# can't access ScrollViewDidScroll function only a void

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview, delegates

for some reason when I try to create a function scrollviewdidscroll, it only gives me an option for a void. I have importedthe scrollviewdelegate and in viewdidload set the delegate to self. I have simply created a scrollview and want to implement some actions but cant get the function only a void. I am new to this so if someone could give me a tip, that would be sweet.

Here is some code :

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to put it inside another function?  You can't do that.

Comment: It is just in the viewdidload

Comment: Also, the `Void` means that the function returns nothing, which is clearly stated in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate method is a **method** - just like `viewDidLoad()`.   You have to declare it as a instance method, not within another method.

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       ...other stuff..
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView:UIScrollView) { 
       ...things that happen when the scrollview scrolls...
    }
}
```